# Which is the best way to code listview

Tags: android

I have been looking for a while now about list-views and spinners etc. My problem is i would like to have a list-view and when a options is picked on my list-view i would like a activity which will display text (information)I would like to know if anyone can show me some examples of this code. Or i mite have it wrong and there maybe a better option for what am after.

Thanks

Comment: Google "Android Listview example" and pick one of the dozens out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this tutorial it will help you
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listviewselection

Comment: Najd thank you for not being 323go and helping me out